# XSLT: How to copy node with UTF-8 attribute when having error 'Cannot convert string "\u4e02" to an integer'?

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, xslt-2.0, saxon

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" width="1000" height="1000" id="svg5496">
  <defs id="defs5498">
    <font-face units-per-em="1024" id="font-face3935" font-family="SVGFont 1"/>
    <missing-glyph d="M0,0h1000v1024h-1000z" id="missing-glyph3937"/>
    <glyph unicode="一" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M21 112H234V93H21V112Z"/>
    <glyph unicode="丁" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M16 196H239V177H144V5Q144 -9 138 -15T113 -21Q98 -21 84 -19L80 1Q95 -2 110 -2Q118 -2 121 0T124 10V177H16V196Z"/>
    <glyph unicode="丂" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M18 193H237V173H93L82 118H217Q217 31 209 5T163 -22Q141 -22 117 -18L111 2Q139 -2 162 -2Q182 -2 188 14T195 98H57L71 173H18V193Z"/>
    <glyph unicode="七" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M241 142L243 123L110 108V15Q110 9 115 7T160 5Q201 5 209 10Q215 14 218 45L239 39Q235 1 226 -7T160 -15Q109 -15 103 -13Q89 -8 89 11V106L16 98L13 117L89 125V201H110V128L241 142Z"/>
  </defs>
  <path style="font-size:800px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;text-align:start;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Droid Sans Fallback;-inkscape-font-specification:Droid Sans Fallback" d="" id="tpl-path"/>
</svg>
```

### XML (`$block`)

The parameter `block` is the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd" > <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
<defs >
<font id="Hanzi-Pinyin-ruby-font" horiz-adv-x="254" ><font-face
    font-family="Droid Sans Fallback"
    units-per-em="256"
    panose-1="2 11 5 2 0 0 0 0 0 1"
    ascent="267"
    descent="-68"
    alphabetic="0" />
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="256" d="M75 183H181V0H75V183ZM88 13H167V170H88V13Z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x4e00;" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M21 112H234V93H21V112Z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x4e01;" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M16 196H239V177H144V5Q144 -9 138 -15T113 -21Q98 -21 84 -19L80 1Q95 -2 110 -2Q118 -2 121 0T124 10V177H16V196Z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x4e02;" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M18 193H237V173H93L82 118H217Q217 31 209 5T163 -22Q141 -22 117 -18L111 2Q139 -2 162 -2Q182 -2 188 14T195 98H57L71 173H18V193Z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x4e03;" glyph-name="null" horiz-adv-x="256" d="M241 142L243 123L110 108V15Q110 9 115 7T160 5Q201 5 209 10Q215 14 218 45L239 39Q235 1 226 -7T160 -15Q109 -15 103 -13Q89 -8 89 11V106L16 98L13 117L89 125V201H110V128L241 142Z" />
</font>
</defs>
</svg>
```

### XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
@description
  Place hanzi and pinyin in the correct element
@upstream: true
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

  exclude-result-prefixes="#default dc cc rdf svg xlink xsl xs"
>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ PARAM +++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<xsl:variable  name="emptyString" select="''" />
<xsl:param   name="hanzi" select="'hanzi'" />
<xsl:param   name="unicode" select="'unicode'" />
<xsl:param   name="pinyin" select="'pinyin'" />

<xsl:param   name="block" select="'NO-TEMPLATE'" />
<xsl:param   name="blockDoc" select="document($block)" />


<!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ TEMPLATE +++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:message>   WIP: <xsl:value-of select="$block" /></xsl:message>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>


<!-- block holding glyph information -->
<xsl:template match="svg:font">
  <xsl:message>count: <xsl:value-of select="count($blockDoc/svg:svg/svg:defs/svg:font/svg:glyph)" /></xsl:message>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*" />
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="from-block"
    select="$blockDoc/svg:svg/svg:defs/svg:font/svg:glyph" />
</xsl:template>


<!-- the character name -->
<xsl:template match="svg:glyph" mode="from-block">
  <!-- <xsl:message>  copying: <xsl:value-of select="@unicode" /></xsl:message> -->

  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  <!-- <xsl:apply-templates /> -->
</xsl:template>


<!-- the character name -->
<xsl:template match="@glyph-name">
  <xsl:variable  name="unicode" select="codepoints-to-string(.)" />
  <xsl:variable  name="hanzi" select="'hanzi'" />
  <xsl:variable  name="pinyin" select="'pinyin'" />

    <xsl:attribute name="glyph-name">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($unicode, ': ', $hanzi, ' /', $pinyin,'/')" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


<!-- the glyph -->
<xsl:template match="@unicode">
    <xsl:variable  name="unicode" select="." />
    <xsl:variable  name="hanzi" select="codepoints-to-string($unicode)" />

    <xsl:attribute name="unicode">
      <xsl:value-of select="$hanzi" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[@id='hanzi-glyph']/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="$hanzi" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[@id='pinyin-text']/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="$pinyin" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Error

```
Validation error at xsl:copy on line 92 of merge-svg.xsl:
  FORG0001: Cannot convert string "\u4e02" to an integer
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:/mnt/data/projects/Hanzi-Pinyin-Font/resources/xslt/merge-svg.xsl#93)
     processing /svg/defs[1]/glyph[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:/mnt/data/projects/Hanzi-Pinyin-Font/resources/xslt/merge-svg.xsl#93)
     processing /svg/defs[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:/mnt/data/projects/Hanzi-Pinyin-Font/resources/xslt/merge-svg.xsl#36)
     processing /svg
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

### Question

I'm using `Saxon-HE 9.5.1.2J` with following command:

```sh
java -jar bin/saxon9.jar \
    -o:./.tmp/batik-unified.svg.tmp \
    -xsl:./resources/xslt/merge-svg.xsl \
    block=./.tmp/batik-CJK_Unified_Ideographs.svg \
    ./.tmp/batik-unified.svg
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The error message does not seem to fit the code sample you have posted. Is there more XSLT code involved, such as one doing `xs:integer(@unicode)`?

Comment: Can you post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Your are using `codepoints-to-string(@unicode)` where that attribute has a string value and not an integer value so that approach is not going to work. I am not sure what you want to achieve with that code, you might need to explain that so that we can suggest an XSLT way of solving your problem without giving errors. `codepoints-to-string(232)` would make sense, to give you an example of the right use of that function, it would give the string `è`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `concat` and `translate` functions along with the `disable-output-escaping` (in XSLT 1.0 mode if necessary) attribute to convert it from a JavaScript style codepoint("\u4E02") to an XML entity ("&#x4e02;") :

For example, this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<foo>bar</foo>
</root>
```

with this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="unicode" select="'\u4E02'"/>
<xsl:variable name="hanzi" select="concat(translate(translate( $unicode, '\u', '&amp;#' ),'E','e'),';')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($hanzi,'#'),'#x',substring-after($hanzi,'#'))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**References**

- [Codepoints: U+4E02 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4E02](http://codepoints.net/U+4E02)
- [Unicode: Yijing Hexagram Symbols](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/yijing_hexagram_symbols.html)
- [Mozilla Unicode Conversion: Japanese Map](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-beta/file/f4157e8c4107/intl/uconv/ucvja/japanese.map)
- [XPath/XQuery Functions: replace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)
- [XSLT FAQ: disable-output-escaping](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2215.html)
- [XSLT FAQ: Special Character handling, Character Maps](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/charmaps.html)
- [Disable-output-escaping and xsl:character-map](http://www.xmlplease.com/xmltraining/xslt-by-example/examples/character-map_1.html)
- [Online XSLT Tester](https://xslttest.appspot.com/)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working example. Use the [XSLT Tester](https://xslttest.appspot.com/) for quick verification.